# Customize Joomla Login Page from Core

Tags: login, wordpress

Like we can edit `wp-login.php` in root folder of Wordpress to customize/change its login page, I would like to know the file name and its location where the HTML form of login page is written in Joomla.

I want to add an OnClick function to the username field.

```
<input name="login" onlick=(test_function)>
```

Comment: The login module or login view in com_users? Which one are you referring to?

Comment: login module. i want to change something in html output in login password filedset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it quite simply then (based on your comment), the file you're looking for is:

> modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php

I would suggest however, you perform a [Template Override](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) to edit this file, rather than editing the core. It will prevent your changes being overridden in a Joomla update.

Hope this helps

Comment: i edited that with the changes i want. and then i opened my login URL - `exmpale.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=login` i never found those changes happened there. any chance there might be some other file,  i need to edit ?

Comment: Ah right' so you.wish to edit the component view, **not** the module. You will need to go to `components/com_users/views/login/tmpl`

Comment: Remember the template override though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512128/how-do-i-edit-my-joomla-login-page i have the same question.  i want to edit the HTML content of the login form. can you help me correct answer ?